# How to force an empty page in a paged HTML document?

Tags: html, css, css-paged-media

How do I force an empty page in HTML document? I have a title page, after which is forced page-break (rule below). The problem is the remaining content is appearing on the directly next page, where I'd want the title page and remaining content to be divided by 1 empty page (pictured below).

HTML:

```
<div class=title-page">
  title
</div>

<div class="content">
  blah blah
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.title-page {
  page-break-after: always;
}
```

Expected result:

```
 -------
| title |
|       |
|     1 |
 ------- 
 -------
|       |
|       |
|     2 |
 -------
 -------
| blah  |
| blah  |
|     3 |
 -------
```

I realize it can be done with inserting an empty `<div>` between title page and the remaining content, then specyfing `page-break-after: always;` on it. Inserting empty div isn't too semantically correct though. Is there a way to achieve the same result using CSS only?

**EDIT:** In this case it could also be done with `page-break-after: left;`, as the first page is a left page by default. What about cases in the middle of the document, where you can't be sure if a page you're on is left or right. Or when you want to insert more than 1 emtpy page. Can it still be done with CSS?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8230317/3340665

Comment: @GhostGambler Right. I should've realized that the first page is a left page and it could be done with `page-break-after: left`. But what about situations when I'd like to insert an empty page in the middle of document, where I don't know if the page I'm on is left or right? Or when I'd want to more than 1 empty page? Can it still be done with CSS?

Comment: According to the answers in the linked question this is not achievable through other means than empty `div` tags.

Comment: I had a similar problem that I solved using paged.js and some hacky tricks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61037614/how-do-i-make-sure-that-my-back-page-content-prints-on-the-back-page-of-a-bookle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A method that works on Chrome and IE, but not Firefox (version 31), is to use a pseudo-element added at the end of the first `div` and to specify a page break before it. To make the pseudo-element non-empty (browsers might otherwise combine the page breaks into one), insert a no-break space there:

```
.title-page:after {
  display: block;
  content: "\A0";
  page-break-before: always;
}
```

Since this does not work in Firefox, it is better to use a dummy `div` element. Note that this will not cause an empty page in Firefox if the element is really empty, `<div></div>`. Instead, put some content there that displays as blank, e.g.

```
<div class="empty-page">&nbsp;</div>
```

(with `.empty-page {   page-break-after: always; }`).

You could also add such a dummy element dynamically with JavaScript, in code triggered by the `beforeprint` event.

Comment: That is an exhausting answer. Thanks.