# How do I make sure that my back page content prints on the back page of a booklet, using paged.js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Given a booklet printed from folded sheets, the back page's number will always be a multiple of 4. If there aren't a multiple of 4 pages of content, the back page will be inside the booklet.

My project is using [Paged.js](https://www.pagedjs.org/) for layout and pagination. (It's very good!) It has a [selector that handles the first page](https://www.pagedjs.org/documentation/05-designing-for-print/#pseudo-class-selectors-for-pages), but not for the last page.

How do I insert blank pages at the end of the document that push the content on the last page onto the back page of the document?

Answer (score 2):

I'd love if someone more competent than me can offer an improved version of this. I suspect that there is a lot that `breakToken` etc. can fix. However, this works for me:

The unpaginated html contains a div with a class of `.back-page`. The strategy here is to look if the page number that the back-page div is on has a page number divisible by 4. If not, insert a big empty div.

### The JS

```js
window.PagedConfig = { auto: false };

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  class MyHandler extends Paged.Handler {
    constructor(chunker, polisher, caller) {
      super(chunker, polisher, caller);
    }

    beforeParsed(content) {}
    afterParsed(parsed) {}
    beforePageLayout(page) {}

    afterPageLayout(pageFragment, page, breakToken) {
      bumpBackPageContentToRealBackPage(pageFragment);
    }

    afterRendered(pages) {}
  }
  Paged.registerHandlers(MyHandler);

  setTimeout(() => window.PagedPolyfill.preview(), 2000); // TODO: swap this for the promise version
});

function bumpBackPageContentToRealBackPage(pageFragment) {
  let backPage = pageFragment.querySelector(".back-page");
  if (backPage) {
    let pageNumberStr = backPage.closest(".pagedjs_page").dataset.pageNumber;
    let pageNumber = parseInt(pageNumberStr, 10);
    console.log("last page is on", pageNumber);
    if (pageNumber % 4 !== 0) {
      console.log("last page needs a nudge");
      let pageDiv = document.createElement("div");
      pageDiv.classList.add("end-vacat-page");
      backPage.parentElement.insertBefore(pageDiv, backPage);
    } else {
      console.log("All is well: last page will print on the back page");
    }
  }
}
```

### The CSS

```css
.back-page {
  break-before: left;
}
.end-vacat-page {
  page-break-before: always;
  height: var(--pagedjs-pagebox-height);
}
```

This triggers a reflow, and then because the back page must be on a left hand page because of one of the Paged.js polyfill rules, it bumps it again until it's on a left hand page.