# vertically align tables when html page is printed

Tags: html, css, printing

I have two tables of size 7cm×15cm that I want to export to a `pdf` file, of A4 portrait paper size, using the browser's "Save to PDF" option in its print tool.

Ideally, I want to vertically center the two tables on the A4 paper. But if that is not possible to do, I would like them to be positioned on the same place in the page.

At the moment, for some reason, the two tables are not positioned at the exact place on the page, as I want them to (see in the image below).

The html code is the following:

```html
<body>
<!-- 1st table: -->
<table>
<tr> <td>content of the first table</td>
<!-- some other tr's and td's -->
</tr>
</table>
<!-- 2nd table: -->
<table>
<tr> <td>content of the second table</td>
<!-- some other tr's and td's -->
</tr>
</table>

</body>
```

together with the following css rules:

```css
table {width:7cm; height:15cm; border: 1px solid;
  page-break-after: always;
  margin: auto;
  }
@media print {
  @page { size: A4 portrait; }
  }
```

The `page-break-after: always;` rule instructs the browser to insert a page break after the table;

The `margin: auto;` rule horizontally aligns the tables on the canvas.

I need to print the two tables on the same paper, in a two-sided printing, so that the tables are printed just behind each other.

What I have at the moment:

[image: illustration]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The most effective way to print a table of HTML data is to use a JavaScript library that can create a PDF document from the table. Don't rely on the browser's "Print to PDF" feature because that will not be simple to produce a well-formatted PDF.

Comment: @daddygames I prefer not to use javascript.

Comment: Good luck, then.

Comment: @daddygames after another thought, could you please mention the library name? I am not that familiar with js, but I better give a look at it.

Comment: It's been a while since I've used JS tools for this task because I usually use an API server instead. My most recent experience for this specific type of task was using [Datatables JS](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html). A quick search seems to point to [jsPDF](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF) as a popular library also, which would give you more options other than just html tables.

Comment: I think, this is the answer to you question. [Even page-break for double-sided printing in HTML & CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230317/even-page-break-for-double-sided-printing-in-html-css)

Comment: jsPDF works great, I have a button that executes tiny javascript to save pdf from the html. https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Tips**]:

@tush, We can do as you mentioned in the comments. Since the height is known AND the container (body) height is known then we can fix them by "manually" positioning it.

Using `margin: 6cm auto;` . Look at the sample below.

[**Result**]:

[Centred PDF file](https://pdfhost.io/v/gl7v5AVVe_A4html)

[**HTML/CSS Code**]:

```css
table {width:7cm; height:15cm; border: 1px solid;
  page-break-after: always;
  margin: 6cm auto;
  }
@media print {
  @page { size: A4 portrait; }
  }
```

```html
<body>
<!-- 1st table: -->
<table>
<tr> <td>content of the first table</td>
<!-- some other tr's and td's -->
</tr>
</table>
<!-- 2nd table: -->
<table>
<tr> <td>content of the second table</td>
<!-- some other tr's and td's -->
</tr>
</table>

</body>
```

Comment: Works. Very simple indeed!

Comment: @tush, I really apologize, I didn't mean that thing.

Answer (score 6):

So I found the fix without javascript. Change your media for print to this:

```css
@media print {
    body {margin-top:0 !important;}
  @page { size: A4 portrait; }

  }
```

Edit for centering the tables:
You have to wrap the tables in a div like this:

```html
<body>
    <!-- 1st table: -->
    <div class="page">
    <table>
    <tr> <td>content of the first table</td>
    <!-- some other tr's and td's -->
    </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
    <!-- 2nd table: -->
    <div class="page">

    <table>
    <tr> <td>content of the second table</td>
    <!-- some other tr's and td's -->
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Then in the css add this for flex display:

```css
@media print {
    body {margin-top:0 !important;}
    .page{
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }

  @page { 
    size: A4 portrait;
  }
  }
```

And it should be centered and all now.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It indeed fixes the position of the tables as I indicated in the attached image. Can you think of a way to position it in the middle of the page too? I came across this [page](http://howtocenterincss.com/). What I understand from there is that if the block element (table in this instance) height is known AND the container (body) height is known then I need to "manually" position it with "padding-top", or something similar. Can you think of a different way?

Comment: I have edited my response and added the centering. I think using display: flex; is better than using paddings and manually calculating the width and all.

Comment: Any by the way, I don't understand why adding `!important` has any effect. When I use the inspect element tool, "Emulate [the] css media type" in "Rendering" and look at the two tables, they both have the same css computed values with and without your change.

Comment: Right now important doesn't do anything, but since there can be other css styles for margin applied to the body either from you or from libraries like bootstrap, `!important` overrides them and makes that style prioritized by the browser.

Comment: @tush can you accept the answer?

Comment: I can give the reputation only after 24 hours. And I would like to wait and see more answers.

Comment: @tush lmao so many contesters to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Here's perhaps one possible solution. I've used your exact provided HTML and CSS, with the simple addition of a `transform` trick which ensures perfect centering of the objects:

```html
<html><head>
    <title>Two Centered Tables</title>
    <style>
        table {
                width: 7cm;
                height: 15cm;
                border: 1px solid;
                page-break-after: always;
                margin: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                text-align: center;
        }

        @media print {
                @page {
                        size: A4 portrait;
                }

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

        <!-- 1st table: -->
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>content of the first table</td>
                    <!-- some other tr's and td's -->
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <!-- 2nd table: -->
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>content of the second table</td>
                    <!-- some other tr's and td's -->
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>


</body></html>
```

## Shown through Chrome DevTools

[image: shown through chrome dev tools]

## Simply using `ctrl/cmd-P` to open print dialogue.

> Here, I've selected 2 pages per sheet just for illustrative purposes to show the perfect alignment. When you do your printing, of course this would be set to one page per sheet (the default). Margins set to none (although auto will work fine too); and background graphics and header **not** selected.
> [image: printing from browser]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Two Centered Tables</title>
    <style>
        table {
                width: 7cm;
                height: 15cm;
                border: 1px solid;
                page-break-after: always;
                margin: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                text-align: center;
        }

        @media print {
                @page {
                        size: A4 portrait;
                }

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="display: grid;">
        <!-- 1st table: -->
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>content of the first table</td>
                    <!-- some other tr's and td's -->
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <!-- 2nd table: -->
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>content of the second table</td>
                    <!-- some other tr's and td's -->
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Try running this snippet, **go to full screen** (after running the snipper → "Full Page" (*not* "Extend snippet"), then print like this:
[image: print ex]
Again, as sanity check only (showing 2 per page to check for alignment):
[image: its aligned]

It may be because of the hard-coding in centimeters, that when you ran this code it didn't work for you; and so it does depend on the actual size of your monitor what you get (if you hardcode width and height in units of cm [or pixels?]?). Can anyone shed light on that?

Comment: I just tried your solution, and [this is the outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9Yd5.png).

Comment: Your approach looks promising, but I can't make it work for some reason.

Comment: That makes a difference, but still not centrally aligned. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvqL4.png)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238452/discussion-between-tush-and-john-collins).